# If a worker is using a CommCare app what is the expected behavior for reaching the log out time limit?

Tags: commcare

If a particular CommCare app has a log out threshold set to, say, 12 hours, what is the expected behavior if a worker is filling out a form when the 12 hour threshold is reached? For example, does the logout wait until the form is complete, or does the app immediately log out regardless of what the worker is doing?

Answer (score 2):

I did some testing with it and here are my observations -

1. Device logs out the user irrespective of what user is doing except when a sync is taking place. In case of a sync, app waits for sync to complete and then logs out the user.
2. If a user is filling a form at the time of auto logout, app always saves the form before logging user out irrespective of whether incomplete is enabled or not for the app. User should then be able to see these by going in 'Saved Forms' and then setting the filter to 'Only Incomplete Forms'. (If incomplete is enabled, user can directly click on Incomplete forms button on home screen)

Answer (score 1):

The expected behavior is that the device logs out as soon as the time threshold is met. So, if a user is working on a form when this happens, the form is saved as incomplete so when the user logs back in they can resume. However, if incomplete forms are not turned on for the app then the progress on the form up until that point is lost.